# Unable to update field security profile for a attribute in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Today i did some security update, and then i found some attributes which was enabled by field security profile, in these field data is not showing and data is present in data base. So i try to disable and delete field security profile but it is showing this error

Unhandled Exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Caller 45844c6e-b79f-df11-aaa1-00155d01f81c does not have full permissions on the attribute 'hrms_lastincrdate' to unsecure the attributeDetail:
 <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
   <ErrorCode>-2147158771</ErrorCode>
   <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
   <Message>Caller 45844c6e-b79f-df11-aaa1-00155d01f81c does not have full permissions on the attribute 'hrms_lastincrdate' to unsecure the attribute</Message>
   <Timestamp>2013-07-08T06:32:05.8793184Z</Timestamp>
   <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
   <TraceText i:nil="true" />
 </OrganizationServiceFault>
```

So please give your precious suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your security profile might not have the required permissions to make that change, are you a system administrator?